# Kick new member if he is not in another server discord.js

Tags: discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
 let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('939185101684744212');

if (guild.member(member)) {
 member.guild.channels.get('939185101684744216').send(' Welcome' );
  

} else { 
  member.kick
  member.send('you should join this server first : https://discord.gg/D7exY52MzG')
}

});
```

Thats the code but im having a lot of problems ._.

like member is undefinded and i hope you help me guys

Answer (score 0):

The bot will have to be in both discord servers for it to check the members of each other. So assuming that is true try this, I haven't tested because I don't have a bot that is in more than one server.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const guild1 = client.guilds.cache.get('the_new_guild_id')
    const guild2 = client.guilds.cache.get('the_id_of_the_other_guild')

    //find memeber in other guild
    const isTrue = guild2.members.cache.find(member => member.id === member.id)

    if (!isTrue) {
        member.send({
            content: `You should join this server first: https://discord.gg/D7exY52MzG`
        }).then(
            //if you don't wait a little the bot won't be able to send the message
            setTimeout(() => {
                member.kick({
                    reason: `Not a member of ${guild1}`
                })
            }, 100)
        )
    } else {
        guild1.channels.cache.get('939185101684744216').send('Welcome' )
    }
})
```